# Highcharts - How show only two series on click

Tags: highcharts

I found this example that half does what I need. I would need it to show two series, not just one.

```
events: {
                show: function () {
                    var chart = this.chart,
                        series = chart.series,
                        i = series.length,
                        otherSeries;
                    while (i--) {
                        otherSeries = series[i];
                        if (otherSeries != this && otherSeries.visible) {
                            otherSeries.hide();
                        }
                    }
                },
                legendItemClick: function() {
                    if(this.visible){
                         return false;   
                    }
                }
            }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tK38J/65/

For example: I click series 1 and I see series 1 and 2. I click series 3 and I see series 3 and 4.
Series 2 and 4 will be hidden in the legend.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link series with the same visibility and hide the other ones in `legendItemClick` event:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function() {
                    if (this.visible) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    this.chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
                        if (s !== this && s !== this.linkedSeries[0]) {
                            s.hide();
                        }
                    }, this);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [...],
        id: 'first'
    }, {
        data: [...],
        linkedTo: 'first'
    }, {
        data: [...],
        visible: false,
        id: 'third'
    }, {
        data: [...],
        linkedTo: 'third'
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s6x37azb/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.linkedTo

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you